# standard materials produced in Unity for Cardboard and Gear VR producing flickering

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, gear-vr

In the image below the green material is a standard material while the surrounding objects have a VertexLit applied.

Any suggestions regarding what materials are best for Mobile VR?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best material for mobile (popular mobiles) is vertexlight mats but if your application don't have up to 200k vertex and heavy animations dont worry for material you can use most of glsl or cgprogram feature your owned material

if your problem is with changing color of material after publishing your game for VR
for textured material select TrueColer in texture properties
for colored material go to lighting setting and change ambient light to gray without any colore like it ( R=30,G=30,B=30)

Comment: Thanks ehsan. I'm just dropping cubes onto the scene and applying a basic color. I get the same flicker with no color added. I'm going to try Maya LT now and see if that solves the problem but it is a little strange that Unity's out of the box 3dobjects and base materials produce all this flickering in the headset.

Comment: your welcome - if your flickers is in black color -> you should select the light in scene and change the range of shadow bios -> if your problem not solved -> change the shadow type in selected light to no shodow and test it - if again have problem you should make your owned render changer to stereo render <- i hope i can help to you  :) ->